# asp.net c# onclick event not firing. Same setup fires on different page

Tags: c#, asp.net

For the life of me I cannot figure out why these `onClick` event handlers are not firing for this particular page.  The exact same setup works on a different page.  On the other page, I made sure an element was set to autopostback, the eventhandlers were created in page load method, and the functions exist and it works.  What could I be missing?

from the .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="forgot.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="forgot" %>
....


<div id="content">

        <asp:Table runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Email Address*</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="emailEntry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="sendPassword" runat="server" Text="Recover Password" causesValidation="true"/>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <asp:Button ID="home" runat="server" text="Goto Main Page"/>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>

From the .aspx.cs file

public partial class forgot : System.Web.UI.Page {

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        bool userLoggedIn = false;
        this.Form.Action="forgot.aspx";

        // get application state
        // save to session if user exists

        if (userLoggedIn) {
             loginButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(logout);
            loginButton.Click -= login;
        } else {
            loginButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(login);
            loginButton.Click -= logout;
        }
        emailEntry.AutoPostBack = true;
        sendPassword.Click += new System.EventHandler(emailPasswordToUser);
        home.Click += new System.EventHandler(goToHomePage);

        ....
    }
}
```

My thoughts are that I have some code that is doing some undefined behavior, which would explain why it works on one page but not the other.  I've added the Form.Action statement from some results of my searches.  I'm new to C# so I'm sure I'm missing some vital setup or somethings and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userLoggedIn) {
             loginButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(logout);
            loginButton.Click -= login;
        } else {
            loginButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(login);
            loginButton.Click -= logout;
        }
```

I would not do this; surely it would be simpler to have one event which you always attach to the button, and figure out whether to login or logout inside the handler ?

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.  I want my functions to have one goal.  The fix, set causesValidation to false for those buttons.